# Plant identification - mediterannean area

Tags: identification

I'm trying to identify this plant :

[image]

It's about 1 meter wide, and leaves are somewhat smelly in an unpleasant fashion. It doesn't seem to flower, or maybe it hasn't yet.

Here is a close up shot displaying some interesting geometry :

[image]

And a third shot at an intermediary distance :

[image]

I leave in the south of france, just on the mediterranean sea. Photos have been taken on the 28th of june 2021.

Thanks !

Comment: The photos are not the best one: low resolution: we cannot zoom. Stem and if it has a wood trunk may help identification.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used higher quality images, and a third one at an intermediary which may help. I have even better images, but can't find a way to get them under the image size limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since then it bloomed, and I identified it as being :

`Dittrichia viscosa`, also known as false yellowhead, woody fleabane, sticky fleabane and yellow fleabane.